# Could not clone mercurial repository in Pycharm

Tags: python, mercurial, ide, pycharm

I am new to PyCharm. When I was trying to clone my project from mercurial, PyCharm continues cloning for ever until I stopped the operation. The test connection was also successful. I was thinking it may be because of not giving my username and password for the repository. But I couldn't find anywhere to pass my credentials. For now I am doing it manually, But I need to know proper solution for this. Please help me by giving me an idea.

Thanks in advance